# Haskell let syntax not working

Tags: haskell

I’m new to Haskell and I’m trying to write a simple program. However, when running the following program:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let w = read (args !! 0) :: Integer
    in print w
```

I get this error message:

> file.hs:4:5: parse error on input `in'

The same `let` syntax works just fine outside of a `do` statement...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `let` syntax is different when inside a `do` block.  You don't need the `in` part, the variable scope is automatically the rest of the `do` block.

In your case:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let w = read (args !! 0) :: Integer
    print w
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record, what is the rule exactly? When do I need to put `in` and when do I need to omit it?

Comment: You use `in` in `let`-as-an-expression, and no `in` in `do` blocks.

Comment: But do note that `let` expressions are valid in `do` blocks as well, as long as they're of the matching monadic type.  Probably pointless, but you could include in your example: `let x = putStrLn "Hello world" in x`

Comment: @Timwi The `let-in` syntax is used when you want to define names for a single expression, such as `f z = let x = 1; y = 2; in x + y + z`.  Here the entire expression is `let x` through `x + y + z`, it returns a value as a unit.  In `do` blocks, `let` is used by itself, since it's defining a value available in a larger scope (i.e. the entire `do` block).  In that case, it isn't returning a value (that's the `in <expr>` part), just binding a name.  It is a bit confusing though, the difference is subtle semantically.

Comment: Or Timwi could indent the last line by one space or more, due to the layout rule.